# executing the python in another python file with arguments as path

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to call a python file `"plotting.py"` in another file `"main.py"`. To execute the `"plotting.py"` file the path should also be given as argument.

So in the `"main.py"` I have executed so

`z='Stream 20170424 15_20_25_856'
os.system('python plotting.py '+z)`

Where variable `z` is the name of the folder and this name, in general, contains the whitespaces and when I execute the `"main.py"` it gives an error. But when I replace the whitespaces in the folder name with `_` and change the variable `z` accordingly and execute the `"main.py"` it executes without an error. But I cannot change the name of the folder every time. So is there any possibility to execute the code changing the folder name and giving the variable `z` has mentioned?

Comment: it is a good practice not to use white spaces in folders' names...

Comment: Use `subprocess.call` with an args list to have it handle the quoting for you. But you shouldn't depend on the working directory to find "plotting.py" if it's relative to "main.py". The working directory is not the same thing as the script directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do not want to remove the whitespaces in your folder's name, put backslashes `\` before the spaces in the variable `z`, to espace them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling python as a command line program you can try adding quotes around the parameter you are passing so that it treats your whitespace'd string as one parameter.  When running commands like that it will treat each space-separated string as a separate parameter to your script if you don't have quotes which is why _'s worked for you.  So your current code passes "Stream" "20170424" and "15_20_25_856" as 3 separate parameters to plotting.py when you want it to be just 1 parameter.

Try

```
os.system("python plotting.py '"+z + "'")
```

Comment: I meant it more that he was running it as a command line program and not that it was specific to os.system.  Also, this would be an issue if he tried to pass parameters like this to any command line program and not just python.

Comment: In general that's right but on Windows it depends on the program. Windows programs get the raw command-line string, and it's up to them how to parse it. In the general case, for all we know a program could require paths to be quoted using a smiley like `☺Stream 20170424 15_20_25_856☺`. ;-) But seriously, by VC++ rules for creating `argv` it should be double quotes,  not single quotes.